# Outlook web addin is not loading in Outlook webApps using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins

I am developing outlook addin for Outlook 2016 , Outlook web App and Outlook 2016 mac. It is Loading for outlook desktop 2016 and MAC. It is not loading in Outlook Web apps. Home  is controller name

Outlook Web apps (OWA) shows[image]

And My MVC view is

```html
@model TEALWebApps.Models.IMAPParam
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" id="viewport"
          name="viewport" />   
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />    
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>   
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>IMAPParam</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImapAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImapAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImapAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PortNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PortNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PortNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Passowrd, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Passowrd, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Passowrd, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:ce44715c-8c4e-446b-879c-ea9ebe0f09c8-->
<OfficeApp
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"
  xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>94dd27bb-79aa-4c79-8321-fbbcebf292f3</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.2</Version>
  <ProviderName>shyams</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="TEALOutlook" />
  <Description DefaultValue="TEALOutlookApps"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:44356/Images/HappyIcon.png" />


  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <!--<AppDomains>
    -->
  <!--<AppDomain>https://addinv4.azurewebsites.net</AppDomain>-->
  <!--
    -->
  <!--<AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>-->
  <!--
  </AppDomains>-->
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44356/Home/Index"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Description resid="residDescription" />
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

          <!-- Message Read -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />

                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44356/Images/icon16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44356/Images/icon32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44356/Images/icon80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44356/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44356/Home/Index"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="My Add-in Group"/>
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="My Add-in Tab"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Show Panel"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Show Pane"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Opens e."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
            <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

            <!-- Message Read -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                  <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                  <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                      <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
                      <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                  <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44356/Images/icon16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44356/Images/icon32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44356/Images/icon80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44356/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44356/Home/Index"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="My Add-in Group"/>
          <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="My Add-in Tab"/>
          <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Show Panel"/>
          <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Show Panel"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Outlook Plugins"/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Is it possible to resolve this issue in OWA?
Thanks in advance
Shyam

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console/debugger?

Usually this means that OWA for whatever reason can't connect to the website that your add-in is located on. Are you testing on the same machine that your web server is running on? (since you are trying to connect to Localhost in your manifest?)

Comment: Yes, I am working on same machine with enable https

Comment: Do I need to add any more code in layout page of MVC ??

Comment: Can you please send me MVC application link  that load in OWA ? I am waiting for your reply . It will be great for me

Comment: Most web browsers prevent external websites from rendering iframes that connect to localhost. Having HTTPS enabled on your local machine is not sufficient and you must have a trusted certificate for local host. In chrome, if you navigate to your site directly (not via OWA) and proceed through the security warning, it will work in OWA for that session. Otherwise you will need to install a self-signed certificate for your root CA of your local machine

Comment: okey , i am sure , i will

Comment: But , I also tried to load asp.net site it is not loading .  What is specification for loading site ? Do I need to add any custom code ??

Comment: What browser are you testing with? Does the site load if you do not include office.js and mock any APIs you're using?

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Does the issue happen in other browsers? like IE, Firefox.

Comment: Yes, It will be better to make sample project in mvc 5 and try to load ,  if you not get error , you can send link here .It will be great for me . I am still getting error that cause i stopped it